# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: html5, angular

Estou com `[(ngModel)]="cliente.nome"` esse codigo fica gerando o erro de:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("="col-md-4 control-label" for="idNome">Nome: </label>
```

E já coloquei o FormModule no *app.module.ts*, mas mesmo asism o erro persiste, segue a estrutura do projeto:

**app.module.ts:**

```
 import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
   @NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent], 
  imports: [
   ...
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**o app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**o atendimento.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AtendimentoRoutingModule } from './atendimento-routing.module';
import { AtendimentoComponent } from './atendimento/atendimento.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AtendimentoRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [AtendimentoComponent]
})
export class AtendimentoModule { }
```

**E o atendimento.component.ts:**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AtendimentoService } from '../atendimento.service';

import { Cliente } from '../../cliente/Cliente'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-atendimento',
  templateUrl: './atendimento.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./atendimento.component.css'],
  providers: [AtendimentoService, Cliente]
})
export class AtendimentoComponent implements OnInit {
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Encontrei o erro no meu codigo, bastou eu adicionar o

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

Dentro do meu atendimento.module.ts, ficando assim import { NgModule } from

```
 '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';  // Adicionei aqui
    import { AtendimentoRoutingModule } from './atendimento-routing.module';
    import { AtendimentoComponent } from './atendimento/atendimento.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AtendimentoRoutingModule,
        FormsModule // Adicionei aqui
      ],
      declarations: [AtendimentoComponent]
    })
    export class AtendimentoModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se depois de importar `FormsModule` o problema persistir, verifique se não há nenhum `<input>` com mesmo nome de outro dentro de seu HTML. Abaixo deixo um exemplo explicando o que digo, veja o atributo `name`.

**Exemplo com problema:**

```
<input ... name="sampleName" [(ngModel)]="myObj"/>
<input ... name="sampleName" [(ngModel)]="myOtherObj"/>
```

**Exemplo revisado:**

```
<input ... name="sampleName" [(ngModel)]="myObj"/>
<input ... name="myOtherSampleName" [(ngModel)]="myOtherObj"/>
```